# Render from Comand line

Tags: rendering, transparency, command-line

I am rendering a scene on some private HPC, they gave me putty to run render with command line:

$ srun -N1 -pgpu blender -b test_gpu.blend  -o //_###.png -P cuda.py -a

everything works fine, but my renders are not on transparent background. How to set alpha in command line or how to use settings from blender??

Tnx in advance,
w7

Comment: Which version of Blender do you use and which version is installed on the server?

Comment: you can make the change in the .blend file before running the command or add the Python commands in to cuda.py or create another Python script that set the Alpha and output type. You can run many Python scripts in a single blender background execution.